# Is there any way to improve contour detection of pupil area from a cartesian iris image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

So, I have this Iris images that i turned into a cartesian images including the pupil area. Now the problem is I need to remove the pupil area from the image. (the pupil area/size are different for each image)

I've tried to mask the pupil area by doing a threshold and finding the contour of the pupil. But the results are not good, because some of the images have light reflection and some have a similar threshold value with the iris area.

```
# convert to binary image
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(image, 35, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

# dilate image to reduce hole in pupil area
kern = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
dilated = cv.dilate(thresh, kern, iterations =1)

# detect contour of pupil area by looking for the biggest contour found
contours,_= cv.findContours(dilated, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
maxContour = 0
for contour in contours:
    contourSize = cv.contourArea(contour)
    if contourSize > maxContour:
        maxContour = contourSize
        maxContourData = contour

# create mask & mask pupil contour area
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
cv.fillPoly(mask, [maxContourData], 1)
masked_pupil = np.multiply(image, mask)
```

I expect only the pupil area is masked, but what i actually got in some images was the pupil area is partially masked and is connected to the iris region.

Here's the result images:
https://postimg.cc/FfGNWfbK
https://postimg.cc/fVcwdqJm

Comment: Could you add one of the problematic images?

Comment: @J.D. I've update the post